# php exception handling issue

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

I am simply trying to put a arithmetic expression around try-catch block.

Here's what I tried:

```
    try 
    {
        $result = 4/0;
    } 
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        d($e->getMessage());
    }
```

But instead of printing `$e->getMessage()`, it is displaying `Internal Server Error Division By Zero` which is similar if I don't use any try-catch.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You got to use this:

```
try 
{
    $result = intdiv(4, 0);
}
catch(DivisionByZeroError $e)
{
    d($e->getMessage());
}
```

PHP manual : http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php (Works with `PHP 7` onwards)

*Update:* Using [`intdiv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) - Integer division (Works with `PHP 7` onwards)

Comment: Amit Merchant, nope still the same.

Comment: I've updated my code. Please try now. Basically I've used [intdiv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) function to perform the division operation which perfectly captures the exception.

Comment: it is still giving me the same `Internal Server Error` despite of all the updates.
is it working on yours as expected?

Comment: Yes. Check here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ace7d2408451c0454c9f835061062bdfa95a97a7

Comment: still getting the Server Error instead of exception message. was it supposed to be so?

Comment: Did you use same exact code I've posted? Please check again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180402/discussion-between-amit-merchant-and-azima).

Answer (score 1):

You can't catch DivisionByZeroError on normal arithmetic because PHP considers it a warning, not an error. Instead you need to set an error handler to look for it e.g.

```
function handler($errno, $error) {
    if ($error == "Division by zero") {
        echo "Error $errno! $error\n";
        return;
    }
    // hand processing back to the standard handler
     return false;
}
set_error_handler('handler');
$result = 4/0;
```

Output:

```
Error 2! Division by zero
```

Note that the error handler should return control to the standard handler (by returning `false`) if this is not the error you were looking for.